# Appending Delayed Evaluation

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have a function that need to be summed over all parameters given in a separate list.

```
f[x_,y_,z_,n_,i_]:= (*Some function*);
list={{n1,i1},{n2,i2},...};
```

I need to create another function that should look like:

```
g[x_,y_,z_]:=f[x,y,z,n1,i1] + f[x,y,z,n2,i2] + ...;
```

for any matching input of list. Is there any way to do it elegantly? I'm thinking about extracting the expression that I typed for f and store it as String then replace the n and i for each pairs in list.

Subquestion:
Is there any way to extract the expression from given input?

Comment: `Total[f[x, y, z, ##] & @@@ list]` ought to work.

Comment: That works. Thanks!

Comment: For the subquestion: not sure what you mean but if you want to prevent the argument of a function from being evaluated (so the expression is passed to the function in its original form), use something like  `SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]`. But in your questions the only "expression" I see is in `list`, and `Lists` of that type aren't evaluated anyway, so you'd have to specify what expression/input you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is to understand the `Apply` operator.  There we want to apply `f` at level 1 to the list.  Therefore, like Guess who it is suggested we can first apply the function `f[x, y, z, ##]` where  `##` gets filled in from your list because of the the `@@@`.  Then `Total` adds up all the functions.

```
Total[f[x, y, z, ##] & @@@ list]
```

Comment: It is actually `f` that gets applied to level 1; that is, all the heads at level 1 (`List`) are changed to `f`. `Total` is equivalent to replacing the head at *level 0* with `Plus`.

Comment: Thanks for catching this.  Answer is updated to reflect your comment.